# krakend lua scripting fail by load lib

Tags: lua, api-gateway, krakend

```
 "endpoint": "/apps/{id}",
      "output_encoding": "no-op",
      "method": "GET",
      "backend": [
        {
          "host": [
            "http://xxx.yyy.zz:8888"
          ],
          "url_pattern": "/apps/{id}",
          "extra_config": {
            "modifier/lua-backend": {
              "sources": [
                "/etc/krakend/Hello.lua"
              ],
              "post": "local r = response.load(); printPostBody(r:body());",
              "allow_open_libs": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
```

My Hello.lua:

```
local mylua = require("cjson")

function printPostBody(body)
    print(body);
end
```

When i add this part: `local mylua = require("cjson")` i got this error:

```
2023/10/08 09:36:23 [Recovery] 2023/10/08 - 09:36:23 panic recovered:
runtime error: slice bounds out of range [-1:]
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:153 (0xf3dc7e)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/krakendio/binder@v0.0.0-20230413105421-1bbe94e65f45/error.go:140 (0x1971f64)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/krakendio/binder@v0.0.0-20230413105421-1bbe94e65f45/binder.go:27 (0x1970866)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/krakendio/binder@v0.0.0-20230413105421-1bbe94e65f45/error.go:201 (0x1972397)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/krakendio/binder@v0.0.0-20230413105421-1bbe94e65f45/binder.go:43 (0x19707ee)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/krakendio/binder@v0.0.0-20230413105421-1bbe94e65f45/binder.go:26 (0x1970785)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/krakendio/krakend-lua/v2@v2.1.2/proxy/proxy.go:75 (0x1979793)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/luraproject/lura/v2@v2.3.0/proxy/balancing.go:77 (0x13080a8)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/luraproject/lura/v2@v2.3.0/proxy/http.go:113 (0x130db84)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/luraproject/lura/v2@v2.3.0/router/gin/endpoint.go:50 (0x1bbf674)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:174 (0x1bb49c1)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/recovery.go:102 (0x1bb49ac)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:174 (0x1bb3ae6)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/logger.go:240 (0x1bb3ac9)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/context.go:174 (0x1bb296a)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/gin.go:620 (0x1bb25f1)
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.9.1/gin.go:576 (0x1bb211c)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2936 (0x128a0b5)
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1995 (0x1285251)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 (0xf761a0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, if you remove the line with a `require` that will work. The thing with Lua in KrakenD is that is not a regular Lua engine, but kind of a virtual machine that is restricted to the standard library and has no dependency injection. You cannot use Lua Rocks neither import anything that is not under the `sources` directory.

So you cannot import Lua libraries like this (require). If you want to include JSON parsing libraries you will need to import them by hand under `sources`.